# Github API: Finding all of the issues closed by a user

Tags: github, github-api

How can I find all the issues closed by a particular user. [GitHub's issues API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues) doesn't support this as a query.

I can scrape this data, but I'd much prefer to get this through their API.

EDIT: I need all closed issues by a user for all time.

Answer (score 3):

Closed issues manifest themselves as issue events in the GitHub API. To access all events, use this pattern with the GitHub API:

`/api.github.com/users/username/events`

For example, to see all of my events: https://api.github.com/users/maxlaumeister/events

To get a list of all the issues the user has closed, filter the JSON response and discard all events except those with `"type": "IssuesEvent"` and `"payload": { "action": "closed", ... }`.

[GitHub API page on IssuesEvents](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#issuesevent)

Comment: Note: the Events API will return up to 300 events per timeline and only events from the last 90 days: https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/

Comment: @IvanZuzak How can I get all events from the beginning of time?

Comment: @MaxWofford As far as I can tell it's not possible to get all events / issues / closed issues by a user for all time. I suspect that GitHub might archive this data. You would need to hit repos individually, list all their issues, and then filter them by user.

Comment: "How can I get all events from the beginning of time?" -- Not possible currently.

Comment: @maximillian-laumeister Hitting every repo's events would work. Is there a time limit on how far back that history goes? [Github's API docs on issue events](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/events/#list-events-for-an-issue) don't mention anything about a history limit.

Comment: @MaxWofford It also looks to me like there's no limit. I would test it out on a repo that has some old issues!